# What does $\mathbb{Q}_2 (\sqrt{7})$ mean and how do I find the minimal polynomial?

Tags: field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I understand what $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{7})$ means, but what does $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{7})$ mean?
Does it have something to do with the P-Adic numbers? I know the minimal polynomial of $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{7})$ is $x^2 - 7$. But how would I find the minimal polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}_2 (\sqrt{7})$?

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: There is no such thing as the minimal polynomial of a field extension. There is only the minimal polynomial of a generator of the extension, but the generator is not unique, so there are many irreducible polynomials that lead to the same field extension.

Answer (score 5):

As $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$, $\mathbb{Q}_{2}(\sqrt{7})$ means the extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$ by adjoining a square root of $7$. Although $\sqrt{7} \not \in \mathbb{Q}$, we *may* have $\sqrt{7} \in \mathbb{Q}_{2}$, i.e. the equation $x^{2} = 7$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_2$. However, this is not true - if such $\alpha$ exists, then we should have $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ (since $|\alpha|_{2}^{2} = |\alpha^{2}|_{2} = |7|_{2} = 1 \Rightarrow |\alpha|_{2} = 1$). Then considering the equation modulo 4 gives contradiction. So $\sqrt{7}$ has degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$, and the minimal polynomial is just $x^{2} - 7$.

Comment: @Seeeoo Lee what about $\mathbb{Q}_2 (\sqrt{9} + \sqrt{5})$? Is that any different from just $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{9} + \sqrt{5})$?

Comment: How exactly do we identify the minimal polynomial? The extended ring also includes the square roots of $-1$, so what makes us choose $x^2-7$ over $x^2+1$?

Comment: Note, NCS, that $\sqrt{17}$ is in the $2$-adics, so ${\bf Q}_2(\sqrt{17})={\bf Q}_2$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Minimal polynomial is about elements, not fields. As you said, we have $\mathbb{Q}_{2}(\sqrt{-1}) = \mathbb{Q}_{2}(\sqrt{7})$. However, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{7}$ can't be $x^{2} +1$, since $(\sqrt{7})^{2} +1 =8$ is not zero.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Sorry it was my mistake - you're right, $\sqrt{5} \not \in \mathbb{Q}_{2}$.

Comment: @NCSapphireGaming Here's the right answer for your question - Since $\sqrt{9} = 3$, we have $\mathbb{Q}_{2}(\sqrt{9} + \sqrt{5}) = \mathbb{Q}_{2}(\sqrt{5})$, and indeed we have $\sqrt{5} \not \in \mathbb{Q}_{2}$ (by the same reasoning above, but contradiction with modulo 8, not modulo 4). The difference between the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$ is that, there are elements not in $\mathbb{Q}$ but in $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$. (like $\sqrt{17}$ as Gerry mentioned). In other words, $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$ is strictly larger than $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Seewoo Lee Why does $\mathbb{Q}_2(3 + \sqrt{5}) = \mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{5})$? Note, I’m in algebra 2 and precalc, but learning abstract algebra for fun.

Comment: @NCSapphireGaming That's essentially because $3 \in \mathbb{Q}_2$. We have $\mathbb{Q}_{2}(3 + \sqrt{5}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_{2}(\sqrt{5})$ since $3 + \sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Q}_{2}(\sqrt{5})$, and vice versa.

Comment: @SeewooLee How would I calculate $\sqrt{9} € \mathbb{Q}_2$? Is it different than $3 € \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $3\in \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}_{2}$.